# How to use Minio with Rust

Tags: rust, minio

I am trying to create an API to use minio with a Rust backend. I tried following [this post](https://github.com/minio/minio-rs) as a starting point but it gives me the error

```
       | use minio::s3::http::BaseUrl;
       |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `minio`
```

I searched for the correct dependency to add to my cargo.toml file, but again I came across [this thread](https://github.com/minio/minio-rs/issues/8) in which the last comment indicates the library is not ready to be used yet.

I am unsure at this point how to move forward. Is it possible to use minio with Rust? If so could anybody help with a more detailed tutorial or documentation please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If/since MinIO is supposed to be S3 compatible, any S3 client library should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crate is not available at crates.io, you can specify it from a git repository as per the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories).

```ini
[dependencies]
minio = { git = "https://github.com/minio/minio-rs.git" }
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I managed to add the crate and now working on the code.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please mark that the answer as resolved to help inform other users.